# Trying to copy a char pointer to a pointer to use with a flood fill function in 2D game

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, flood-fill

As part of a 2D game I am building I need to check if there is a valid path for the game to be completed. It was recommended that I do a copy of the map and use flood fill to check the validity. The characters in the game are a 'P (player), 'E' (exit), 'C' (collectable), '1' (wall) and '0' (spaces). I have a typedef structure called t_map that holds all of my game variables.

Currently it is seg faulting on the flood fill but this is because the copy_map is not working. I have only started c programming six months ago so to get to this stage has been a challenge. So my understanding of what should happen is:

1. copy each line of the map.ber file using the copy_map function.
2. if it finds a 'C' change to a '0' and increment copy_ccount.
3. else if it finds an 'E' change to a '0' and increment copy_ecount
4. if it is an '0' use flood fill to check each space around it and move through the map "painting" the '0' with a 'P'.
5. do a check against ccount and ecount from the original map and if they are different throw an error.

My question is instead of trying to copy it line by line should I in fact be opening the map and reading it again? I've had help with the read_map function and the copy_map function from two different people so trying to tie it all together is proving difficult. Thanks for any assistance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void    copy_map(char **origin, char **copy)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (copy[i])
    {
        origin[i] = ft_strdup(copy[i]); //this is my own strdup function
        i++;
    }
    origin[i] = NULL;
}

static void flood_fill(t_map *map, int paint, int y, int x)
{
    if (map->map_copy[y][x] == 'C')
    {
        map->copy_ccount++;
        map->map_copy[y][x] = '0';
    }
    else if (map->map_copy[y][x] == 'E')
    {
        map->copy_ecount++;
        map->map_copy[y][x] = '0';
    }
    if (map->map_copy[y][x] == '0')
    {
        map->map_copy[y][x] = paint;
        flood_fill(map, paint, y, x + 1);
        flood_fill(map, paint, y, x - 1);
        flood_fill(map, paint, y + 1, x);
        flood_fill(map, paint, y - 1, x);
    }
}

int valid_path(t_map *map, int y, int x)
{
    map->map_copy = ft_calloc(1, sizeof(map->map)); // this is my own calloc function
    y = map->playery;
    x = map->playerx;
    copy_map(map->map, map->map_copy);
    flood_fill(map, 'P', y, x);
    if (map->ccount != map->copy_ccount)
    {
        closeprogram("Map cannot be solved\n");
    }
    if (map->ecount != map->copy_ecount)
    {
        closeprogram("Map cannot be solved\n");
    }
    return (1);
}
```

This is the original read_map function and the main that pulls it all together.

```
t_map   *read_map(char *argv )
{
    t_map   *new;
    int     y;

    new = (t_map *) ft_calloc(1, sizeof(t_map));
    new->fd = open(argv, O_RDONLY);
    new->h = 0;
    new->w = 0;
    y = 0;
    if (new->fd < 0)
    {
        ft_putstr("Map file does not exist\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    while (get_next_line(new->fd))
        new->h += 1;
    close (new->fd);
    new->map = (char **) ft_calloc(new->h + 1, sizeof(char *));
    new->fd = open(argv, O_RDONLY);
    while (y < new->h)
    {
        new->map[y] = get_next_line(new->fd);
        y++;
    }
    while (new->map[0][new->w++ + 2])
        close(new->fd);
    return (new);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    t_map   *map;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        ft_putstr("Error\nInvalid number of arguments. Must be 2\n");
        return (1);
    }
    if (check_map_file(argv[1]))
        return (1);
    map = read_map(argv[1]);
    init_components(map);
    valid_map(map);
    map->mlx = mlx_init();
    map->win = mlx_new_window(map->mlx, map->w * 32, map->h * 32, "so_long");
    render_map(map);
    parse_map(map);
    mlx_hook(map->win, 17, 0, exitprogram, NULL);
    mlx_hook(map->win, 2, 1L << 0, keypress_hook, map);
    mlx_loop(map->mlx);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: In `read_map()`, what's `while (new->map[0][new->w++ + 2]) close(new->fd);` doing? Can't guess how many times this might be trying to close a file... You need to take a break, then read the code **carefully** without _knowing_ that it _should_ be just great...

Comment: How big is your map, because recursively calling that `flood_fill` function is just asking for the stack to overflow.